# Error when getting mouse move coords and dividing them by 32 (Math.Floor)

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Create Graphics
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

    mx = Math.Floor(e.X / 32);
    my = Math.Floor(e.Y / 32);
}
```

Getting an error under `Floor` in `mx` and `my` (mx and my are both integers)

> Error: Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Math.Floor(decimal)' and
>   'Math.Floor(double)'  GameAttempt3    c:\users\levyjrdesktop\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\GameAttempt3\GameAttempt3\Form1.cs   95  Active

Comment: Add the error to the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is two overload of the `Floor` method ([`Double`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx),[`Decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
public static decimal Floor(decimal d);
public static double Floor(double d);
```

So you need to cast:

```
mx = Math.Floor((double)e.X / 32);
my = Math.Floor((double)e.Y / 32);
```

Comment: Or optionally make it `32.0` to use the double overload and drop the cast.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually **no need to call `Math.Floor(..)`: [`e.X`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.x(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`e.Y`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.y(v=vs.110).aspx) are already integers**, and a division between two integers, will generate the integral part.

So you can simply write:

```
mx = e.X / 32;
my = e.Y / 32;
```

Or in case you want to use `Math.Floor` (since integer division is a bit different from `Floor` division, you can **divide by `32.0d`** to make it a double:

```
mx = (int) Math.Floor(e.X / 32.0d);
my = (int) Math.Floor(e.Y / 32.0d);
```

You then thus have to cast to an `int` again.

Comment: @KHF445: what do you mean with didn't work. Please provide some information.

Comment: gives me another error when using .0 or .0d

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) GameAttempt3 c:\users\levyjrdesktop\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\GameAttempt3\GameAttempt3\Form1.cs 97 Active

Comment: @KHF445: should be fixed.